# Spring DI: Specify default component for FactoryBean<T>

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have two implementations of interface `IFoo`: `Foo1` and `Foo2`.

I need the context to be able to inject the correct one for any class that wants an `IFoo` without that class knowing what implementation it's going to get (so no use of `@Qualifier`).

Example of usage:

```
class Bar { 
  @Autowired IFoo foo;
}
```

I have a `FactoryBean<IFoo>` class that has the logic for which one to return.

The issue is that I also want to have those two impls go through the IOC because they have dependencies themselves.

```
public class FooFactory implements FactoryBean<Foo> {
  @Autowired Foo1 foo1;
  @Autowired Foo2 foo2;

  @Override
  public IFoo getObject() throws Exception {
    if(someLogic()){
        return foo1;
    }
    return foo2;
   }
}
```

If I autowire them into the factory I get an exception of

```
"No unique bean of type IFoo is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: [fooFactory, foo1, foo2]"
```

Any way to tell spring to just use the default of fooFactory for everyone else but use the two implementations inside the factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the notion of the "primary" bean.  Assuming that you're using XML config, then:

```
<bean id="fooFactory" class="x.y.FooFactory" primary="true"/>
```

Now, `@Autowired IFoo foo` should select the result of the factory, in preference to the `foo1` and `foo2` beans.

I would also recommend using `@Resource` inside the factory itself, rather than `@Autowired`, i.e.

```
public class FooFactory implements FactoryBean<Foo> {
  @Resource Foo1 foo1;
  @Resource Foo2 foo2;
```

This reduces the chance of the autowiring chasing its own tail, since `@Resource` will inject a specific, named bean (i.e. `foo1` and `foo2`). You'd still use `@Autowired` in `Bar`.

If you use `@Resource` like that, then an alternative to use `primary="true"` is to exclude the `foo1` and `foo2` beans from autowiring, e.g.

```
<bean id="foo1" class="x.y.Foo1" autowire-candidate="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a list:

```
@Resource
private List<IFoo> foos;
```

Unfortunately it might not work since you are currently constructing `FooFactory`, so you might get circular dependency error. Try it!

But the more idiomatic wat since Spring 3.1 would be to use `@Profile` or `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
public IFoo foo() {
  if(someCondition) {
    return new Foo1(dep1(), dep2());
  else
    return new Foo1(dep3(), dep4());
}
```

Where `dep...()` methods are also `@Bean` declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You can trz to annotate the factorys result wiht `@Primary`.

I have not tryed it, and have no IDE here to test it, but may it works.

```
@Configuration
public class MyFactory {

  @Bean
  @Primary
    public IFoo getFoo () {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at bean factory scopes.

- [related post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830337/spring-factorybean-and-scopes-working-together)
- [Spring Bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)